# Aptana Auto Complete Woes, deletes a few lines after use..

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Aptana has recently starting behaving strangely. Every time I use the auto complete feature, and hit the tab key in order to complete, it will delete 2 or 3 lines below it.  This results in having to undo the auto complete and typing the file name or directory name manually. It seems to only happen when auto completing the src attributes.  Auto completing anything else seems to work fine.

Anyone else seen this? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Aptana a few times with no luck.  I've also tried creating new projects to see if it was specific to the project, and also have tried disabling the Content Assist and the Auto Complete and that doesn't even seem to work.

I'm running Aptana 3.2.0.201... On a Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Thanks in advance, this problem is really annoying the hell out of me.